# trying to download the word document using open xml from dot net core mvc getting an error

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to generate the word document using open XML plugin in Dot net core  by writing code in action result method inside controller like this below

```
    public IActionResult CreateDocument()
    {
        using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
            {
                wordDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
                Document doc = new Document();

                //Body body = new Body();

                /// Add header
                MainDocumentPart mainDocPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;

                HeaderPart headerPart1 = mainDocPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>("r97");

                Header header1 = new Header();

                Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph() { };
                Run run1 = new Run();
                Text text1 = new Text();
                text1.Text = "This is Header Part";

                run1.Append(text1);
                paragraph1.Append(run1);
                header1.Append(paragraph1);

                headerPart1.Header = header1;

                // getting an error here in this line
                SectionProperties sectionProperties1 = mainDocPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SectionProperties>().FirstOrDefault();  
                if (sectionProperties1 == null)
                {
                    sectionProperties1 = new SectionProperties() { };
                    mainDocPart.Document.Body.Append(sectionProperties1);
                }
                HeaderReference headerReference1 = new HeaderReference() { Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default, Id = "r97" };
                sectionProperties1.InsertAt(headerReference1, 0);
             .......
            ........
            .........
           }
        }
     }
```

but some how getting an error at this line `SectionProperties sectionProperties1 = mainDocPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SectionProperties>().FirstOrDefault();`

`**Error:**  DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.MainDocumentPart.Document.get returned null.`

i am not sure where i am doing wrong with this code, Could any one please suggest any idea on this one

many thanks in advance

Comment: would any one  please let  me know where i am doing wrong with this

Comment: Well it says that `MainDocumentPart.Document == null`, so maybe you must add you `doc` to the `mainDocPart`?

Comment: @EnigmaState, have a look at my answer for some hints on how you can improve your code in this specific case and in general when it comes to Open XML.

Comment: @ThomasBarnekow thanks for pointing me in right direction i have solved that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instantiate the `mainDocPart` variable at this line:
`MainDocumentPart mainDocPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;`

Then you did not add any document in it. That's why you are got the error: `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.MainDocumentPart.Document.get returned null.`

How to solve it:

```
mainDocPart.Document = doc; //you define earlier but do not used.
doc.Body = new Body();
SectionProperties sectionProperties1 = 
mainDocPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SectionProperties>()?.FirstOrDefault();  
if (sectionProperties1 == null)
{
    sectionProperties1 = new SectionProperties() { };
    mainDocPart.Document.Body.Append(sectionProperties1);
}
```

You can get more information about it in this doc page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.document?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=openxml-2.8.1

Answer (score 1):

To add to Lutti's answer, you need to understand that the minimum `WordprocessingDocument` consists of a `MainDocumentPart` the content of which is at least the following:

```xml
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:body />
</w:document>
```

Thus, when you create an "empty" document, you should have at least the following code:

```cs
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(stream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
    mainDocumentPart.Document = new Document(new Body());
}
```

Note the correspondence of the `w:document` and `w:body` elements with the `Document` and `Body` instances.

Using the creation of the header as an example, you can generally streamline your code by combining the constructors and, thus, creating XML markup-like structures as follows:

```cs
var headerPart = mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();
headerPart.Header =
    new Header(
        new Paragraph(
            new Run(
                new Text("This is the Header Part"))));
```

In the above code example, I've laid out the code like you would format the corresponding Open XML markup:

```xml
<w:hdr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:p>
    <w:r>
      <w:t>This is the Header Part</w:t>
    </w:r>
  </w:p>
</w:hdr>
```

In my mind, this is much easier to read and, if you understand the Open XML markup required to create the desired outcomes, helps avoid errors.